# Saving AJAX page state

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hashchange

Is there any way to listen for hashchanges in the url and log the event for use of a backbutton in AJAX etc.

Using links like such:

```
<a href="/#!page">Go to page!</a>
```

and script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        if (window.location.hash){contentload(window.location.hash);}

        $('a').click(function() {
            fragment = this.hash;
            contentload(fragment);
        });

    });

    function contentload(fragment) {
        fragment = fragment.slice(1).replace('!', '')
        $('#content').load('http://mysite.com/'+fragment+'?ajax=1');
    }

</script>
```

I need to try and save the state of the page, Ive seen the [jQuery address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) but have no idea how to implement this..

Comment: Quit writing tags in titles please.

Comment: Sorry man, never realised the police were on to me

Comment: Please use "@name:" syntax to notify other users of replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this using the jQuery Address plugin

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this jquery plugin 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: this plugin requires a `#` on every href if im right? i need my pages to be followed by search engines, thus it is not practical